# creating k-elements set from 1-element set

Tags: java, for-loop, data-mining, apriori

I have an declared an ArrayList a = [1,2,3,4,5] in java. I created another ArrayList b using the loop below:

```
for(int i = 0; i<a.size(); i++)
{
      for(int j=i+1; j<a.size();j++)
      {
              b.add("{" + a.get(i)+ "," + a.get(j) + "}");
      }
}
```

Now the ArrayList b will contain elements [{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{1,5},{2,3},{2,4},{2,5},{3,4},{3,5},{4,5}]. Now if I print the statement using System.out.println(b.get(0)), then the output will be {1,2}.

Now, I want to create 3-element sets from the 2-elements set c = [{1,2,3},{1,2,4},{1,2,5},{2,3,4},{2,3,5},{3,4,5}].

Again, I want to create 4-element sets from the 3-element set above as d = [{1,2,3,4}, {1,2,3,5},{1,2,4,5},{2,3,4,5}]

Again I want to create 5-element set lilkewise... How can I modify the above loop system to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Put that in a method that takes two sets `s1`, `s2`.
2. To generate `b`, just call the method with `(a, a)`.
3. To generate `c`, just call the method with `(a, b)` or `(b,a)`.
4. Repeat at will.

You just have to add some logic to remove the `}` or `{` from the items in the set. Alternatively, don't put them at all and use them only to print results.

Comment: that is a great idea actually. Had not considered one.... I will try it!!!

Answer (score 0):

I've written a recursive method to do make all permutations of an array of numbers for you:

```
public static void main(String ... args) {
    List<Integer> numbers= new ArrayList<>();
    numbers.add(1);
    numbers.add(2);
    numbers.add(3);
    numbers.add(4);
    numbers.add(5);

    for (int i=0; i<numbers.size(); i++) {
        dfs(numbers.get(i), numbers, new ArrayList<Integer>(), numbers.size(), 0);
    }
}

private static List<List<Integer>> resultOfResults= new ArrayList<>();

private static void dfs(int startNumber, List<Integer> numbers, List<Integer> result, int depth, int currentDepth) {
    result.add(startNumber);
    for (int i= 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
        if (!result.contains(numbers.get(i))) {
            dfs(numbers.get(i), numbers, new ArrayList<Integer>(result), depth, currentDepth + 1);
        }
    }
    if (currentDepth + 1 == depth) { 
        resultOfResults.add(result);
        return;
    }
}
```

Then, just go over `resultOfResults` and print each array:

```
for (List<Integer> result : resultOfResults) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result.toArray()));
}
```

Comment: Thank You!! I will certainly try it out!

Comment: Why is the message of diamond operator not supported in Java being displayed? It says that my source is 1.6 and asks me to use source 7. How to do that?

Comment: Aha, just don't use diamond operator but instead of `List<Integer> numbers= new ArrayList<>();` put `List<Integer> numbers= new ArrayList<Integer>();` . Same goes for: instead of `private static List<List<Integer>> resultOfResults= new ArrayList<>();` put `private static List<List<Integer>> resultOfResults= new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();`

Comment: I did: private static List<List<Integer>> resultOfResult = new ArrayList(); (without diamond operator) and it worked.

Comment: But my problem is not about finding permutation. It is as i have stated above. Can you provide me a solution for it too?

Comment: Then I don't understand what you want